# Codeforces test server error, not reproducible on local machine

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  long long n = atoi(argv[1]);
  long long m = atoi(argv[2]);
  long long a = atoi(argv[3]);

  if (n == 0 || m == 0 || a == 0) {
    std::cout << "" << 0 << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }

  long long num_tiles = ceil(n / a) * ceil(m / a);

  if (num_tiles == 0) num_tiles = 1;

  std::cout << "" << num_tiles << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This produces an error ("Runtime error on test 1") on the Codeforces test servers using GNU C++ 11. I am using `g++ -std=c++11 ...` to compile my code locally, which works fine. I have also gotten the same error for all of my other solutions to problems. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is not in the compilation (despite your `#include` 'style' being deprecated since the 90s), your program is incorrect. For starters, independent of what this is supposed to do, `ceil(n / a)` does not make sense.

Comment: @BaummitAugen can you please constructively elaborate on your comment

Comment: Well, as `n/a` is an integer, why do you call `ceil` on it? Also, use `cstdlib` instead of `stdlib.h`, `std::atoi` (wrong choice of function for the given LHS btw, read the docs) instead of `atoi` and so on.

Comment: `ceil` is called because I do not want floor division. I've updated headers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen How is it deprecated?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because the standard (yes, even C++ 98) says the C standard headers `<xxx.h>` are deprecated.

Comment: note that `atoi` converts to int, not `long long`. You could use `atoll` or preferably `strtoll`. (The `ato...` family causes undefined behaviour if the input is out of range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are the culprit :

> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
>   long long n = atoi(argv[1]);
>   long long m = atoi(argv[2]);
>   long long a = atoi(argv[3]);
> ```

In Online Judges you have to take input from Standard Input (STDIN) and output to Standard Output (STDOUT).

Use any of the standard methods like `scanf` or `cin` to take your input and use `printf` or `cout` to give your output. Don't expect anything useful in `argc` or `argv`.

Have a look at this [FAQ on Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/417).

An excerpt from another famous online judge [Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/), which also applies to Codeforces.

> If you use any method other than using the standard input and output streams - for example, using command line arguments, reading from a file, opening up some sort of dialog box, or otherwise - you will never be judged correct.